# Multiple subset sum calculation

Tags: python, algorithm, math, subset, subset-sum

I have 2 sets, set A contains set of random numbers and set B's elements are sum of set A's subsets.

For example,

```
A = [8, 9, 15, 15, 33, 36, 39, 45, 46, 60, 68, 73, 80, 92, 96]

B = [183, 36, 231, 128, 137]
```

I want to find which number is sum of which subset with data like this.

```
S = [[45, 46, 92], [36], [8, 15, 39, 73, 96], [60, 68], [9, 15, 33, 80]]
```

I was able to write really dumb brute force code with python.

```
class SolvedException(BaseException):
    pass

def solve(sums, nums, answer):
    num = nums[-1]

    for i in range(0, len(sums)):
        sumi = sums[i]
        if sumi == 0:
            continue
        elif sumi - num < 0:
            continue
        answer[i].append(num)

        sums[i] = sumi - num

        if len(nums) != 1:
            solve(sums, nums[:-1], answer)
        elif sumi - num == 0:
            raise SolvedException(answer)

        sums[i] = sumi

        answer[i].pop()

try:
    solve(B, A, [list() for i in range(0, len(B))])
except SolvedException as e:
    print e.args[0]
```

This code works pretty well for small datas, but it will take billion years to calculate my data(which has 71 numbers and 10 sums).

I could use some better algoritms or optimization.

Sorry for my bad English and terrible unefficient code.

---

Edit : Sorry, I realized that I didn't described the problem accurately.

As every single element in `A` are used to make elemens of B, `sum(A) == sum(B)`

Also, set `S` **must be** partition of set `A`.

Comment: looks like knapsack/backpack problem to me. Look it up

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah you are right, it was wrong code. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to find all sets which yield a given target sum or just one set? Also, are the numbers in `A` assumed to be nonnegative?

Comment: you got that right now :)

Comment: There are many possibilities here, what's your criteria for selecting a subset?

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm trying to find all sets, and elements in set `A` are all positive.

Comment: Trying to find *all* sets could very well be infeasible, and doesn't match your sample output (where you simply give a single subset of A for each element of B).

Comment: What are the constraints? How many elements will it be at most in the first set, in the second set and what will be the maximum value of the elements of the first set?

Comment: @JohnColeman Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your question. One set is enough and I don't think more than one set will be possible with my data.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko I want to calculate [this data](http://pastebin.com/VgSweUvJ).

Comment: Is `S` a partition of `A`?

Comment: For your specific case it is possible to create an algo with DP that will not run very long (a couple of minutes as I can think). Take a look at hivert's answer.

Comment: @EricDuminil what does `S` being `A`'s partition mean? `S` should have every elements of `A`.

Comment: Then it's a partition ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is known as the subset-sum problem and it is a well known NP-complete problem. So basically there is no efficient solution. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

However If your number N is not too large, there is a pseudo polynomial algorithms, using dynamic programming:
You read the list A from left to right and keep the list of the sum which are doable and smaller than N. If you know the number which are doable for a given A, you can easily get those which are doable for A + [a]. Hence the dynamic programming. It will typically be fast enough for a problem of the size you gave there.

Here is a Python quick solution:

```
def subsetsum(A, N):
    res = {0 : []}
    for i in A:
        newres = dict(res)
        for v, l in res.items():
            if v+i < N:
                newres[v+i] = l+[i]
            elif v+i == N:
                return l+[i]
        res = newres
    return None
```

Then

```
>>> A = [8, 9, 15, 15, 33, 36, 39, 45, 46, 60, 68, 73, 80, 92, 96]
>>> subsetsum(A, 183)
[15, 15, 33, 36, 39, 45]
```

---

After OP edit:

Now I correctly understand you problem, I'll still think that your problem can be solved efficiently, provided you have an efficient subset-sum solver: I'd use divide and conquer solution on B:

- cut B into two approximately equal pieces B1 and B2
- use your subset-sum solver to search among A for all subsets S whose sum are equal to sum(B1).
- for each such S:

  - call recursively solve(S, B1) and solve(A - S, B2)
  - if both succeed you have a solution

However, your (71, 10) problem below is out of reach for the dynamic programming solution I suggested.

---

By the way, here is a quick solution of your problem *not* using divide and conquer, but which contains the correct adaptation of my dynamic solver to get all solutions:

```
class NotFound(BaseException):
    pass

from collections import defaultdict
def subset_all_sums(A, N):
    res = defaultdict(set, {0 : {()}})
    for nn, i in enumerate(A):
        # perform a deep copy of res
        newres = defaultdict(set)
        for v, l in res.items():
            newres[v] |= set(l)
            for v, l in res.items():
                if v+i <= N:
                    for s in l:
                        newres[v+i].add(s+(i,))
                        res = newres
                        return res[N]

def list_difference(l1, l2):
    ## Similar to merge.
    res = []
    i1 = 0; i2 = 0
    while i1 < len(l1) and i2 < len(l2):
        if l1[i1] == l2[i2]:
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1
        elif l1[i1] < l2[i2]:
            res.append(l1[i1])
            i1 += 1
        else:
            raise NotFound
            while i1 < len(l1):
                res.append(l1[i1])
                i1 += 1
                return res

def solve(A, B):
    assert sum(A) == sum(B)
    if not B:
        return [[]]
        res = []
        ss = subset_all_sums(A, B[0])
        for s in ss:
            rem = list_difference(A, s)
            for sol in solve(rem, B[1:]):
                res.append([s]+sol)
                return res
```

Then:

```
>>> solve(A, B)
[[(15, 33, 39, 96), (36,), (8, 15, 60, 68, 80), (9, 46, 73), (45, 92)],
 [(15, 33, 39, 96), (36,), (8, 9, 15, 46, 73, 80), (60, 68), (45, 92)],
 [(8, 15, 15, 33, 39, 73), (36,), (9, 46, 80, 96), (60, 68), (45, 92)],
 [(15, 15, 73, 80), (36,), (8, 9, 33, 39, 46, 96), (60, 68), (45, 92)],
 [(15, 15, 73, 80), (36,), (9, 39, 45, 46, 92), (60, 68), (8, 33, 96)],
 [(8, 33, 46, 96), (36,), (9, 15, 15, 39, 73, 80), (60, 68), (45, 92)],
 [(8, 33, 46, 96), (36,), (15, 15, 60, 68, 73), (9, 39, 80), (45, 92)],
 [(9, 15, 33, 46, 80), (36,), (8, 15, 39, 73, 96), (60, 68), (45, 92)],
 [(45, 46, 92), (36,), (8, 15, 39, 73, 96), (60, 68), (9, 15, 33, 80)],
 [(45, 46, 92), (36,), (8, 15, 39, 73, 96), (15, 33, 80), (9, 60, 68)],
 [(45, 46, 92), (36,), (15, 15, 60, 68, 73), (9, 39, 80), (8, 33, 96)],
 [(45, 46, 92), (36,), (9, 15, 15, 39, 73, 80), (60, 68), (8, 33, 96)],
 [(9, 46, 60, 68), (36,), (8, 15, 39, 73, 96), (15, 33, 80), (45, 92)]]

>>> %timeit solve(A, B)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop
```

So it is quite fast for this size of problem, though nothing is optimized here.

Comment: It does seem related to the subset-sum problem but it isn't exactly the same problem AFAICT. It also looks like `S` is a partition of `A`. You're right though, it's most certainly NP-hard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and code! Actually, it is little bit different from normal subset-sum problem. I updated the question, can you please check it again please?

Comment: The problem is that if you find a subset for a sum (e.g. `[9800000, 225000, 2805000, 4505000, 154000, 9570000, 7670300]` for `34729300`), you might have used an element that should be used for another sum (e.g. `37047600`). @hivert's method is fast and works fine, but you'll need some extra logic and backtracking to find the correct partition.

Comment: Notice that your solution is not in the global solution problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

A complete solution, which compute all the manner to do a total.
I use ints as characteristic sets for speed and memory usage : `19='0b10011'` represent `[A[0],A[1],A[4]]=[8,9,33]` here.

```
A = [8, 9, 15, 15, 33, 36, 39, 45, 46, 60, 68, 73, 80, 92, 96]
B =[183, 36, 231, 128, 137]

def subsetsum(A,N):
    res=[[0]]+[[] for i in range(N)]
    for i,a in enumerate(A):
        k=1<<i        
        stop=[len(l) for l in res] 
        for shift,l in enumerate(res[:N+1-a]):
            n=a+shift   
            ln=res[n]
            for s in l[:stop[shift]]: ln.append(s+k)
    return res

res = subsetsum(A,max(B))
solB = [res[b] for b in B]
exactsol = ~-(1<<len(A))

def decode(answer):
    return [[A[i] for i,b in enumerate(bin(sol)[::-1]) if b=='1'] for sol in answer] 

def solve(i,currentsol,answer):
        if currentsol==exactsol : print(decode(answer))
        if i==len(B): return
        for sol in solB[i]:
                if not currentsol&sol:
                    answer.append(sol)
                    solve(i+1,currentsol+sol,answer)
                    answer.pop()
```

For :

```
solve(0,0,[])

[[9, 46, 60, 68], [36], [8, 15, 39, 73, 96], [15, 33, 80], [45, 92]]
[[9, 46, 60, 68], [36], [8, 15, 39, 73, 96], [15, 33, 80], [45, 92]]
[[8, 15, 15, 33, 39, 73], [36], [9, 46, 80, 96], [60, 68], [45, 92]]
[[9, 15, 33, 46, 80], [36], [8, 15, 39, 73, 96], [60, 68], [45, 92]]
[[9, 15, 33, 46, 80], [36], [8, 15, 39, 73, 96], [60, 68], [45, 92]]
[[15, 15, 73, 80], [36], [9, 39, 45, 46, 92], [60, 68], [8, 33, 96]]
[[15, 15, 73, 80], [36], [8, 9, 33, 39, 46, 96], [60, 68], [45, 92]]
[[45, 46, 92], [36], [15, 15, 60, 68, 73], [9, 39, 80], [8, 33, 96]]
[[45, 46, 92], [36], [9, 15, 15, 39, 73, 80], [60, 68], [8, 33, 96]]
[[45, 46, 92], [36], [8, 15, 39, 73, 96], [60, 68], [9, 15, 33, 80]]
[[45, 46, 92], [36], [8, 15, 39, 73, 96], [15, 33, 80], [9, 60, 68]]
[[45, 46, 92], [36], [8, 15, 39, 73, 96], [60, 68], [9, 15, 33, 80]]
[[45, 46, 92], [36], [8, 15, 39, 73, 96], [15, 33, 80], [9, 60, 68]]
[[15, 33, 39, 96], [36], [8, 15, 60, 68, 80], [9, 46, 73], [45, 92]]
[[15, 33, 39, 96], [36], [8, 9, 15, 46, 73, 80], [60, 68], [45, 92]]
[[15, 33, 39, 96], [36], [8, 15, 60, 68, 80], [9, 46, 73], [45, 92]]
[[15, 33, 39, 96], [36], [8, 9, 15, 46, 73, 80], [60, 68], [45, 92]]
[[8, 33, 46, 96], [36], [15, 15, 60, 68, 73], [9, 39, 80], [45, 92]]
[[8, 33, 46, 96], [36], [9, 15, 15, 39, 73, 80], [60, 68], [45, 92]]
```

Notice than when the two `15` are not in the same subset, the solution is doubled.

It resolves the unique solution problem :

```
A=[1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, 1011,
   1012, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1023,
   1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028, 1029, 1030, 1031, 1032, 1033, 1034, 1035,
   1036, 1037, 1038, 1039, 1040, 1041, 1042, 1043, 1044, 1045, 1046, 1047, 
   1048, 1049]

B=[5010, 5035, 5060, 5085, 5110, 5135, 5160, 5185, 5210, 5235]
```

in one second. Unfortunately, it's not yet enough optimized for a (71,10) problem.

Yet another one, in the pure dynamic programming spirit : :

```
@functools.lru_cache(max(B))
def solutions(n):
    if n==0 : return set({frozenset()}) #{{}}
    if n<0 :  return set()
    sols=set()
    for i,a in enumerate(A):
            for s in solutions(n-a):
                if i not in s : sols.add(s|{i})
    return sols

def decode(answer): return([[A[i] for i in sol] for sol in answer]) 

def solve(B=B,currentsol=set(),answer=[]):
    if len(currentsol)==len(A) : sols.append(decode(answer))
    if B:
        for sol in solutions(B[0]):
            if set.isdisjoint(currentsol,sol):
                solve(B[1:],currentsol|sol,answer+[sol]) 

sols=[];solve()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and code. As the problem is NP-Complete and set of number is too big, I guess its time to give up on this problem. Thank you again for your answer!

Comment: I add some explanations. What is your 71,10 problem ? I am interested in try to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, here's the [link](http://pastebin.com/VgSweUvJ) to the actual data.

Comment: As even smallest number of subsets possible was larger than 1400, I thought it is not possible nor efficient to calculate all possivle subsets first then find not duplicating answer.

Comment: Yes. I quickly reach A 4Go table. It's really a hard problem ;) .